# Why is the log of the discount curve used?

Tags: discount-factor-curve

I was reading here:   [SAP S/4HANA Software Documentation](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_S4HANA_ON-PREMISE/ab2cb3cae60b45dd861f79c60f4cbdcc/327fab41fca2444a9f0b82f62039a9fb.html)

> *Calculation Methods for Interpolating the Yield Curve*
>
> The option Linear Interpolation of Log( Discount Factor ) means the
> system keeps instantaneous or differential forward rates constant
> between the grid points. This method is very robust and can also work
> in borderline cases where the other calculation methods lead to an
> error during yield curve creation.

I vaguely recall seeing this in Bloomberg, also.  What is the robustness that is mentioned above?

Comment: This may help: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2005.13890.pdf . Really, everyone should read Attack68's book.

Comment: @DimitriVulis Thanks.  Will you give me the title or ISBN of the book?

Comment: Sure: [_Pricing and Trading Interest Rate Derivatives: A Practical Guide to Swaps_ (2E, , 2022) by J. Hamish M. Darbyshire](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0995455546) ISBN 978-0995455542